# New iframe in DOM can't get it's height

Tags: jquery, iframe

When the page loads I apply this code below to set the height of the iframe based on the height of the content within the iframe, **this part works**.

```
$("iframe").height($("iframe").contents().height());
```

I have an iframe on the page and I update the iframe src via jquery. Then at the end of the operation I run the above code again, there's new content, therefore it would make sense to run it again and apply the new height to the element, **this part doesn't work**.

I can't get the update iframe (with the new src) (and new content) to have the correct height.

I've even tried getting rid of that specific iframe and creating a new one in it's place.

```
var iframe = $("<iframe>")
    .attr("frameborder", "0")
    .attr("src", "/code?"+string)
$("#form-demos").html(iframe);
```

This doesn't work either.

The height just keeps returning 150 when it should be 345.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to swap out `.ready()` for `.load()`!!!

Comment: `.ready()` fires every time, `.load()` doesn't fire on reload, I think it's because the iframe is cached. So I needed to use both.